# group the email address which are highly count in list

Tags: php

i am working with CRM which is written in php , i need to create a group of email address which are highly used for example :

```
emailFirst@domain.com
emailThird@domain.com
emailThird@domain.com
emailScond@domain.com 
emailThird@domain.com
emailScond@domain.com
```

here is i want as :

```
emailThird@domain.com (3)
emailScond@domain.com (2)
emailFirst@domain.com (1)
```

i tried the code in php like that :

```
$string_emails = "emailFirst@domain.com emailThird@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailScond@domain.com emailThird@domain.com emailScond@domain.com";
$emails = str_word_count($string_emails, 1);
$ret = array_count_values($emails );
print_r($ret);
```

But no luck it's show me just word only.

Thanks.

Comment: stop chaining function calls like that. it makes it impossible to debug. `$arr = str_word_count(...); var_dump($arr); $ret = array_count_values($arr); var_dump($ret)` is FAR easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks Marc i will take care of this

Comment: `array_count_values(explode(' ', $string_emails))` is probably about all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string_emails = "emailFirst@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailThird@domain.com emailScond@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailScond@domain.com";
$emails = explode($string_emails, ' ');




print_r(array_count_values($emails));
```

output:

```
Array ( 
[emailFirst@domain.com] => 1 
[emailThird@domain.com] => 3 
[emailScond@domain.com] => 2 )
```

Comment: -1. imploding a string is pointless. implode expects an ARRAY as its input

Answer (score 1):

```
$string_emails = "emailFirst@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailThird@domain.com emailScond@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailScond@domain.com";
// we create an array with the values if you really want to have an str for your values
$emails = explode( ' ', $string_emails );

$emails_list = array();

foreach($emails as $item)
{
    $emails_list[$item] = $emails_list[$item]+1;
}

print_r($emails_list);
```

Comment: -1. imploding a string is pointless. implode expects an ARRAY as its input.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$emails = "emailFirst@domain.com emailThird@domain.com emailThird@domain.com 
emailScond@domain.com emailThird@domain.com emailScond@domain.com";

$array = array();
$array = explode(" ",$emails);

if(sizeof($array) > 0 ){
 $final_array = array();
 foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  $final_array[$val] += 1 ;
 }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output ::

```
Array ( [emailFirst@domain.com] => 1 [emailThird@domain.com] => 3 [ emailScond@domain.com] => 1 [emailScond@domain.com] => 1 )
```

**UPDATE**

Found an issue, extra space may cause issue so this line will fix this

```
   $final_array[trim($val)] += 1 ;
```

instead of

```
   $final_array[$val] += 1 ;
```

Comment: you are rewriting the internal array_count_values(), which is likely faster

Comment: Yeah sometime I just cant remember the function names and so just write the logic but yes as you suggested internal functions are faster :)

Comment: Thanks abhik but i was needed to be in group like that : 
Array ( 
[emailFirst@domain.com] => 1 
[emailThird@domain.com] => 3 
[emailScond@domain.com] => 2 )